# Evaluating *ngIf inside every *nFor loop in Angular 7

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if, angular7

I'm trying to use the following statement in my Angular template

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let sequence of sequences; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="displayNewDate(sequence.start)">
    <p>{{ sequence.start | date:'shortDate' }}</p>
  </div>
  {{ sequence.content }}
</ng-container>
```

Where as the method `displayNewDate(sequence.start)` checks if the current date has been displayed, and displays it if not. Therefor I want the *ngIf to vary between true and false.

```
public displayNewDate(current) {
    const currentDate: Date = new Date(current);
    if (!this.previousDate) {
      this.previousDate = currentDate;
      return true;
    } else if (this.previousDate.getFullYear() < currentDate.getFullYear()) {
      this.previousDate = currentDate;
      return true;
    } else if (this.previousDate.getFullYear() == currentDate.getFullYear() && this.previousDate.getMonth() < currentDate.getMonth()) {
      this.previousDate = currentDate;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

However I get the following in the console:

> ERROR Error: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
>   has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: true'.
>   Current value: 'ngIf: false'."

Is this a limitation to the ***ngIf** directive? If so, is there an alternative way to get a list of sequences, and everytime a sequence beginning at a date different from the previous sequence, display the new date above the given sequence.

Comment: That is not related to for-if combination. Even more - it is not related to ngIf perse but the way angular binds values to UI (and checks for modifications afterwards)

Comment: Your method is supposed to be idempotent: if nothing else changes in the state of your app, two subsequent calls to the method with the same argument are supposed to return the same value. That's not the case. Don't change the state of your component when evaluating an expression, i.e. calling a getXxx method.

Comment: @JBNizet What are the alternatives?

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: Use the actual state to return the correct value. Get the actual previous date from the array, and check if it's different from the current one. Or precompute that once, storing in each sequence if it should display the start or not. This method is called at each change detection, for each sequence. Not just once for each sequence.

Comment: @JBNizet Okai, thanks for the alternatives :)